# Using the Collections.max for a Period (java)

Tags: java

So I have a `List<Period> periods = new Arraylist<>();` which stores my dates which it gets from the database. (Period being my own class, forgot to mention)

The List kinda looks like this: `2012-02-03, 2012-02-04, 2012-03-05, 2012-03-07, 2012-03-08, 2012-03-09, 2012-03-10` and I need to find the biggest period out of the list. So the outcome would have to be `period: 2012-03-07 to 2012-03-10`.

Now I thought I would use the collection method like this: `Period biggestperiod = Collections.max(periods);` except it doesnt work and I get the next error: "max(java.util.Collection) in Collections cannot be applied to (java.util.List) reason; no instance of type variables T exist so that Period conforms to Comparable .

Im a complete noob when it comes to programming so could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: well "Period" is not "Comparable". if you can't compare 2 periods, you can't find the max

Comment: About what `Period` are you talking? A `List<java.time.Period>` doesn't store dates.

Comment: Is `Period` a class that has a notion of a start and end date? Or does it just contain 1 date or a list of dates? In your example, why should `2012-03-07 to 2012-03-10` be considered the biggest? Because it is most recent or because it has the most number of days?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe There is another class where you set the begin and end date and in that range the Period class will look for the most consecutive days. So I need to return the biggest period, yes. Lets say that it looks in a period of a month, like whole November. It takes ALL the dates and stores it, so im trying to find the biggest period in the list. Hope it makes sense, im kinda new to this

Answer (score 1):

I'm *guessing* `Period` is one of your own classes, if it's Java's `Period`, you have to use `Collections.max` with the additional `Comparator`  you cannot use the `Collections.max` function without it. To use the `Collections.max` method without an additional `Comparator`, `Period` has to implement `Comparable` - `java.time.Period` doesn't.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection) for reference and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html for the `Period` class.

I just wrote a simple example of how this works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Number implements Comparable
{
public int number;

public Number(int number)
{
    this.number = number;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg0)
{
    if (number > ((Number) arg0).number) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (number == ((Number) arg0).number) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (number < ((Number) arg0).number) {
        return -1;
    }
    return -2;

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Number one = new Number(1);
    Number three = new Number(3);
    Number two = new Number(2);

    List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    numberList.add(one);
    numberList.add(three);
    numberList.add(two);

    System.err.println(Collections.max(numberList).number);
}
}
```

Comment: It's still possible to use `Collections.max`, but the overload with the extra `Comparator` argument.

Comment: Period is indeed my own class. Forgot to mention that, sorry about that.

Comment: Woops, you're right @Clashsoft! 
@Shirohige you should have provided that class in your initial post :)

Comment: @maio290 Like the whole class? It's like over 700 lines or something :O